# Not able to install Impala in Ambari Server

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, thrift, impala

I have installed Ambari server on my CentOS server. I want to read real-time data from Hive so I am trying to install Impala but I am not able install it.

I have take reference from following link.

https://github.com/cas-bigdatalab/ambari-impala-service

I am not able to identify that where & which file need to put Impala Repo code.

The Repo code is as follows

```
[cloudera-cdh5]
# Packages for Cloudera's Distribution for Hadoop, Version 5, on RedHat or CentOS 6 x86_64
name=Cloudera's Distribution for Hadoop, Version 5
baseurl=https://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/redhat/6/x86_64/cdh/5/
gpgkey =https://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/redhat/6/x86_64/cdh/RPM-GPG-KEY-cloudera    
gpgcheck = 1
```

I am a bit stuck to go ahead.

Comment: It could be helpful to know, what "*I am not able to install it*" really means. Are there any error messages that you could copy+paste here? Any other potentially relevant information? And how is that related to [tag:thrift]?

Comment: Hi JenesG, I have installed it but now impala service automatically stopped after one min. I checked my impala log I got this below error.   log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
F0523 06:27:58.890755 28608 impalad-main.cc:64] NoSuchMethodError: setCaching.  Regarding thrift server Actullay I want to fetch realtime data from hive database using php.php need to connect with thrft to hbase or hive not directly.

Answer (score 0):

For CentOS, repos always go under /etc/yum.repos.d/.  Put the file there and you should be able to run:

```
# yum install impala
```